# SQL query the last row of referenced User ID

Tags: sql

I got the table having User ID with reference previous referenced ID inside table as below.

How could query the earliest reference ID with result of its date ?

```
User ID     Previous ID Date
9990002939  9990000321  Apr-08
9990000321  9990000021  Apr-04
9990000021  9990000015  Jun-02
9990000015              May-00
```

If provided ID is 9990002939 ->  Query result should be 
9990000015              May-00

Comment: please tag what is your DBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming SQL Server, so method might be different depending on what you're actually using.

You can use a recursive cte:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT * ,Rnk = 1
             FROM Table1
             WHERE UserID = '9990002939' 
             UNION ALL
             SELECT a.*,Rnk = Rnk+1
             FROM Table1 a  
             JOIN cte b
               ON a.UserID = b.PreviousID)
     ,cte2 AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Rnk DESC)'RowRank'
               FROM cte)
SELECT *
FROM cte2
WHERE RowRank = 1
```

[SLQ Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06e9a2/2/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT USER_ID,DATE,MIN(USER_ID) AS mini FROM YOUR TABLE HAVING USER_ID=mini
```